# Does multi-player client render distance affect server view distance for that player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

This is a question about multi-player Minecraft.

If a server view distance is set to 10 chunks, and a client render distance is set to 2 chunks, will the server only load 2 chunks for that player or the entire 10 chunks?

i.e. does the server load `min(client_render_distance, server_view_distance)` chunks?

Comment: I timed it: It took me 7 minutes to test this (just to make sure, I had already assumed that it was true what I wrote in my answer), including setting up the server. Self-answers are encouraged here, so you can also ask the question and immediately post your own answer if you know it and want to contribute to the knowledge base of this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server loads as many chunks distance around a player as its server render distance is set to.

If you set the server render distance to 32 and your client render distance to 2 and fly 100 blocks away from e.g. a repeating command block, the command block still executes its command. It only stops when you go over 32 chunks away.